# Access localhost in Docker using WSL2 on Windows 11 without using Docker Desktop in 2024?

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I just can't make it work. I've tried so many solutions but they error out or just plain don't work.

For example, this worked `docker run --rm -ti -p 80:80 nginx` while accessing `localhost` but my Next.js app doesn't.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: easypanel-nextjs:0.0.1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: nextjs-sqlite
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

#### Dockerfile

```json
EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME localhost
```

I tried accessing my IP address using `ipconfig` but that doesn't work. I tried `0.0.0.0:3000`, `127.0.0.1:3000`, `host.docker.internal:3000` & `localhost:3000` but none of them work.

The only thing that currently works is changing `HOSTNAME` environment variable to like this:

```json
ENV HOSTNAME '0.0.0.0'
```

#### .wslconfig

```bash
[wsl2]
localhostforwarding=true
```

I even tried mirrored mode networking to make localhost work but it didn't work. I didn't restart my PC but I used the following config & did `wsl --shutdown` too.

#### .wslconfig

```bash
[wsl2]
localhostforwarding=true
networkingMode=mirrored
firewall=true
```

I don't want to write a script on every restart. I even tried [this solution](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-1926022445) which suggests no restart is required but [it gave me an error.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-1960753784).

How do I solve it? Its 2024. Docker on Windows is such a pain to make work even with WSL2. I had the same issue with Docker Desktop so I uninstalled it thinking WSL2 would solve my problem but still face the same problem.

I temporarily solved my problem by commenting these 2 lines in my `Dockerfile` but Idk everyone uses the same lines just fine:

```bash
EXPOSE 3000

# This somehow makes it work. Im using the default Next.js + Docker template from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile
# ENV PORT 3000
# ENV HOSTNAME localhost
```

What's the simplest solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used the latest version of Windows & WSL2, I removed `.wslconfig` & made it entirely empty.

And then just used `0.0.0.0` in my Dockerfile instead of `localhost` & everything worked.

For more info, [follow the links from this comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-1968230138)

I wish `localhost` worked but this is as easy as it gets.

This is really hard to debug if you use services like Redis with environment variable `REDIS_HOST=localhost`. You have to point it to `0.0.0.0` too.